# Bash: command substitution with multiple unset/export commands

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I am trying to unset some variables and export others using command substitution. This works:

```bsh
$(echo "
    export TEST_A=1
    export TEST_B=2
")
```

And this too:

```bsh
$(echo "
    unset TEST_A
    unset TEST_B
")
```

However, this fails with Bash 4.3.30(1)-release on both OSX and Debian Jessie:

```bsh
$(echo "
    unset TEST_A
    export TEST_B=1
")
# bash: unset: `TEST_B=1': not a valid identifier
```

Is this an expected behavior, and how can one unset and export multiple variables using command substitution?

To provide some context: here is the related [issue in boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/716).

Comment: It seems to work if you turn the unset and export lines around; do the unset last.

Comment: No, this does not work either: when I make `unset` command last, it has no effect. Try this: `$(printf "export A=1\nexport B=2") && echo "A: $A, B: $B"`, then `$(printf "export C=3\nunset A") && echo "A: $A, B: $B, C: $C"`. You'll see that `A` is still set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In:

```
$(echo "
  export TEST_A=1
  export TEST_B=2
")
```

being `$(...)`, just one expansion is parsed as a simple command.

So that `$(...)` expansion undergoes the split+glob operator. The output of `echo` is trimmed of its trailing newline characters and split into several words on IFS characters (newline, space and tab by default):

- `export`
- `TEST_A=1`
- `export`
- `TEST_B=2`

And each word undergoes globbing. Here they expand to themselves since they don't contain wildcard characters. So after globbing, we still have the same list of four strings.

The command to run is derived from the first one. Here `export` and all those strings are passed as arguments to that command. So, here, it's as if you had written:

```
export TEST_A=1 export TEST_B=2
```

So you're exporting the `TEST_A` variable with value 1, the `export` variable without changing its value and the `TEST_B` variable with value 2.

In the last one, you're running:

```
unset TEST_A export TEST_B=1
```

If you want the output of `echo` to be treated as shell code to interpret, that's where you want to use `eval` **and** not use the *split+glob* operator (quote your command substitution):

```
eval "$(echo "
  unset TEST_A
  export TEST_B=1
")"
```

That one is also a *simple command*. Two strings: `eval` and `<newline><spaces>unset TEST_A<newline><spaces>export TEST_B=1`.

`eval` evaluates the content of its arguments as shell code. So it runs those two shell command lines: `unset TEST_A` and `export TEST_B=1` (again, two *simple commands*).

Comment: The weird thing is that `unset TEST_A;\nexport TEST_B=1` (i.e. just add a semicolon at the end of the unset line in the third example in the original question gives the error `'TEST_A;' not a valid identifier`, which is not quite what you'd expect even if the whole thing is interpreted as one line; keywords here are *simple command*, the whole thing is interpreted as one command and not per se as one input line.

Comment: @wurtel, would you expect `echo $(cmd)` to run `rm -rf ~` if `cmd` did output `foo;rm -rf`?

Comment: Stéphane, thanks for the answer! So it seems that command substitution is not the right way to evaluate output of `boot2docker shellinit`, which prints several lines with `unset` and `export` commands to stdout, and the proper way is to use something like process substitution: `. <(boot2docker shellinit)`. Am I correct?

Comment: @sam.kozin, use `eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"` if that's outputting shell code. IIRC, `. <(...)` used not to work in `bash`, but should be OK with bash4.

Comment: @stéphane, yes, that thing outputs shell code (which consists of a bunch of `unset` and `export` commands), and `eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"` works. Thank you! :)

Comment: Tested `. <(boot2docker shellinit)` just now, it works in Bash 4.3.30. But I'll definitely use your solution with `eval`, because it doesn't require a recent version of Bash.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas As I said, the keyqords are *simple command*, i.e. not a compound one. You're finishing the point I was making...: you'd expect the one thing, but that doesn't happen because it's a simple command.